# Custom action just after commit deployment phase of publishing transaction

Tags: publishing, publishtransaction

Is it possible to invoke some custom action just after commit deployment phase of publishing transaction? If Yes, can you provide me some references towards it?

I know that we can use deployer extension that gets executed during deploy/undeploy phases. However I am looking for the custom action to get executed just after commit deployment phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a module, deriving from `com.tridion.deployer.Module`. This module can then be placed in a **separate** *Processor* node in your cd_deployer_conf.xml, where you can add a **phase** to the configuration element, which in your case would then be: **post-transaction**.

In total it would look like this:

```
    <Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction">
         <Module Type="PageDeploy" Class="my.custom.package.PostTransactionDeploy">
    </Processor>
```

This can also be done for the **Undeploy** action.

Alternatively, you could have a look at the [SI4T Storage Extension](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/tree/master/storage-extensions), where it is also possible to do stuff *post-transaction*.

Comment: Storage extensions are for extending storage behavior so they operate on asset changes instead of the publish transaction; for post-transaction stuff I would always recommend using a module and not a storage extension because storage extensions aren't modular...

Comment: @Raimond, I have tried the option which you have provided, unfortunately it does not seems to work. Does the inclusion of phase='post-transaction' attribute in Processor node executes the custom module just after Commit deployment phase?

Comment: Indeed it runs exactly when the transaction has been committed succesfully. You should see "Executing phase: post-processing for transaction: <id>" in the logs. If you don't see that line or any subsequent action, probably something in your config is off. Could you post that please?